# Overwriting in CPP

Tags: c++, overwrite

I'm writing a piece of code, using C++, I'd like to avoid overwriting and write various files every 1000 timesteps. This is within a time loop:

```
fstream out("ux.odt");
for (auto &row: ux) {
    for (auto col: row)
        out << col << ',';
    // cout << col <<',';
    out << '\n';
```

It gives me the results only for the last timestep. How can I get files for let's say time step 1000, 2000, 3000?

Comment: Please clarify, you state you don't want to over write, but the code suggests you always write to the same file.

Comment: You seem to think C++ works like Python. It does not. Use curly braces around your for loop bodies if they have more than one statement.

Comment: Are you looking for `std::ios_base::app`? Or are you looking for a way to create seperate files?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try something like this:

```
std::ofstream out;
static bool first_pass = true;
if (first_pass)
{
    out.open("ux.odt");
    first_pass = false;
}
if ((timestamp % 1000) == 0)
{
    out.close();
    std::ostringstream filename;
    filename << "ux_" << timestamp << ".odt";
    out.open(filename.str());
}
//... code to write to the file.
```

The first line creates a stream variable for writing.

The second line declares a Boolean variable that is initialized at program start up to "true" to indicate a first pass or not.

The first "if" statement, will initialize the output filename to "ux.odt", on the first pass through the code.

The second `if` statement will close the existing file and create a new file, every 1000 time stamps.